# Maintaining a single executor service and shutting it down appropriately

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

My application requires that a certain job be done asynchronously, so I've resorted to the executor framework. This job (a `Runnable`) is expected to be run should a certain external interface be down (the vendor could be backed up for a while, say, 30 mins).

With this ask in mind, I believe I should maintain a single scheduled executor service with a fixed no. of core threads that perform these jobs when the interface I said above goes down for a brief moment (as a `static` variable in the class I need the thread pool in). I also don't think I should create an executor for every need to handle such a job (single scheduled thread pool executor), and shut down after a job is run, because that would defeat my purpose, wouldn't it? Because that could mean reserving a thread for every job during the backed up hour which sounds scary to me.

But, if I were to maintain such a single executor service, when would I be shutting down the executor? I understand that an executor once shut down can't be reused, while not shutting down the executor and keeping threads active could prevent the JVM from shutting down. How do I go about this?

My last statement was based on this from `Effective Java 2nd edition`:

> And here is how to tell the executor to terminate gracefully (if you
>   fail to do this, it is likely that your VM will not exit):
>
> `executor.shutdown();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This job (a Runnable) is expected to be run should a certain external
>   interface be down (the vendor could be backed up for a while, say, 30
>   mins).

Above is your requirement. Now the solution entirely depends on how above situation is handled.

- **Trigger or event listener**: If you have some trigger or event listener which can be called when it is found that a certain external interface is down, then in the that triggered code or event listener, you can create a `ExecutorService`, execute all your tasks (you can choose on fixed or pooled thread pool), and then on completion of all tasks, you can shutdown the `ExecutorService`
  In this case, it is a good idea to create a `ExecutorService`, do tasks and shut it down. No need of long running `ExecutorService`.
- **Track or periodic check**: If you have to track or check periodically  whether certain external interface is down or not, then I think you can have a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` implementation to have check after fixed time interval whether certain external interface is down or not, and if it is down then execute all your tasks. In this case you will NOT shutdown your `ExecutorService` and it will always be running.

  - Check [scheduleAtFixedRate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) and [scheduleWithFixedDelay](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) for periodic task scheduling.

*P.S.: Trigger and Track are my own convention I used tangentially as one word, so do infer it in technical words.*

> I understand that an executor once shut down can't be reused, while
>   not shutting down the executor and keeping threads active could
>   prevent the JVM from shutting down.

Yes, an executor once shut down can't be reused.
No, a running `ExecutorService` will not stop you JVM shutdown, but once JVM is shutdown that `ExecutorService` instance and its thread pool will be stopped and destroyed.

Comment: Added a reference from `Effective Java 2nd edition` that lead me to think JVM exiting will have problems in the case in OP. So perhaps I misunderstood it? Can you clarify?

Comment: And my case is slightly a "Track" style although can be argued to be "Trigger" styled too. There's no periodic check involved, but I'd like to run the jobs with a scheduled delay of 60sec. Would you recommend a single (static) `ExecutorService` in this case?

Comment: JVM shutdown is really much more complex by having shutdown hooks etc., so there could be many situations when JVM shutdown may wait before shutdown, but in this particular case of statement in "Effective Java", I guess (I am not sure, they didn't elaborate) they could probably be referring that while executor service is running and there are few thread of executor running. But in practical its not very likely that all the threads of executor will be running, when threads are in executor thread pool then they are in waiting state and not active. Any non-daemon active thread can make JVM wait.

Comment: Since "Effective Java" has mentioned so there should be some point, but there is no much clarification on the same. If that is to be true then try this - In a simple Java program, create an executor service and do not shutdown the executor, then you will see that JVM has not finished, now you can shutdown the JVM by CTRL+C or shutdown button, and you will see that JVM has shut down. So, it means JVM shuts down. We also have executor service in our applicaiton and we never saw that JVM shutdown halting because of executor service.

Comment: Since your requirement is a continuous process, I would say on startup of your server, spawn a new thread and create the executor service there and its related code. In that way you need not to have a static executor and there are no chance that while the same JVM instance is running, that code of executor will be invoked again.

Comment: @mystarrocks Did you get a chance to give a try that a running ExecutorService doesn't block the JVM shutdown? What you decided for placing executor service code and when to call it?

Comment: I decided to let the executor keep running. I did simple tests and it seems that JVM exiting had no problems that way, but I'd love to know the explanation of that statement. Accepted anyway!

Comment: @mystarrocks Yes, I am certainly going to share it over here in your question, as soon as I have little time to create some POC's to understand how and what they exactly mean, there could be something very specific case but in whole it works, even in my prod app, everything works. Thanks.